Encontré esta oración en wikipedia y no la entiendo
"Del medio físico forman parte el relieve de los continentes, mares y océanos, que es muy estable porque los cambios son lentos, y se hacen visibles con el paso de los años."
La única parte que entiendo yo es la última. "se hacen visibles con el paso de los años" creo que significa "are made visible with the passing of years" pero lo demás, no puedo entender.

"Del medio físico /forman parte el relieve de los continentes/, mares y océanos/, que es muy estable porque los cambios son lentos, y se hacen visibles con el paso de los años."
Spanish can put words in a different order that an English speaker is not used to.
El relieve de los continentes, mares y oceanos forman parte del medio físico, lo que es muy estable porque los cambios son lentos, y se hacen visibles con el paso de los años."
They can put the subject after the object.
Here's what an English speaker expects:
The relief of the continents, seas and oceans form part of the physical medium (environment), which is very stable because changes occur slowly and become visible with the passage of time.

‘The physical environment includes the relief of continents, seas and oceans, which is very stable because changes are slow, and become visible over the years’.

"Del medio físico forman parte el relieve de los continentes, mares y océanos becomes in English: The relief of the continents, seas and oceans are [forms] part of the physical medium

Me parece que los angloparlantes no son fuertes en la estructura de las frases, porque para mí es exactamente lo mismo.

No tiene nada que ver con si son fuertes o no en la estructura de las frases. Se trata de explicar a un anglofono como funciona.
